# DocumentReference#onSnapshot event firing when data added even though it doesn't match the query

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

I have a collection "users" in firestore. Each doc has a username as its key and has a collection called "notifications" inside.

The following code runs upon app load, presumably setting up an event listener of sorts to detect when changes occur.

```js
    const notificationRef = this.$db.collection(USERS).doc(this.currentUser().userName).collection("notifications");

    notificationRef
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
          switch (change.type) {
            case "added":
            case "modified":
                console.log("Detected new or updated notification: ", change.doc.data());
                this.$store.commit("setNotification", {key: change.doc.id, ...change.doc.data()});
              break;
            case "removed":
                console.log("Detected deleted notification: ", change.doc.data());
                this.$store.commit("removeNotification", change.doc.id);
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        });
        this.$forceUpdate();
      });
```

Here is how I am adding notifications to the db.

```js
async sendInvites() {
      var invitedMembers = [];
      var notInvited = [];
      var batch = this.$db.batch();

      const userQuery = this.$db.collection(USERS).where('email', 'in', Object.values(this.data));

      // We have to 'await' on this so that we can use the batch write
      await userQuery
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            // Make sure we don't invite the current user!
            if (doc.data().email !== this.currentUser().email) {
              invitedMembers.push(doc.data().email);
              const currentUser = this.currentUser();
              batch.set(doc.ref.collection('notifications').doc(), {
                text: `Invited you to join "${this.currentGroup.value.name}"`,
                action: "invite",
                by: {
                  userName: currentUser.userName,
                  displayName: currentUser.displayName,
                  photoURL: currentUser.photoURL
                },
                group: this.currentGroup.key
              });
            }
          });
        });

      batch.commit().then(() => {
        Object.values(this.data).forEach(value => {
          if (!invitedMembers.includes(value)) {
            if (value !== "") {
              notInvited.push(value);
            }
          }
        });
        console.log("Invited members: ", invitedMembers);
        console.log("Not invited: ", notInvited);

        if (notInvited.length > 0) {
          this.errors.notInvited = `The following members could not be found and were not invited: ${notInvited}`;
        }
      });
    }
```

Scenario:

Current User: kylon

Notification added to: tyner

The problem is, if I add a notification to tyner while kylon is currently logged in, the notification shows up as an add and is therefore being displayed to kylon's frontend (only initially, when I reload the page, it loads in the correct documents).
I have checked firestore and it is saving in the correct spot ("users/tyner/notifications/").

Since I am querying for the user doc with the current user's username "kylon", I would assume that firestore would only provide snapshots that satisfy that criteria, but that is not the case.

Could anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

Comment: This will be a lot easier to debug if you remove all variables, call users by their actual UID (instead of "A" and "B"), and show exactly what you are doing to add data to the specific collections.  What you have right now is just too abstract to work with easily.

Comment: Editing now, thanks

Comment: I tried to add as much as I could. Let me know if you think anything else will be helpful

Comment: I was able to workaround this by moving notifications as a top-level collection. I'm not sure why that works, but watching a nested collection doesn't. I would still love to see if anybody has an answer for this. It's almost like putting onSnapshot on (users/<username>/notifications) was actually watching (users) for ANY changes.

Comment: Putting a snapshot listener on a subcollection definitely will not yield changes to documents in any other collection, even the parent document.

Comment: That's good to know! It must have been some silly thing I was doing then.